# PASS DATA FROM MODEL TO BLOCK

Tags: blocks, api, model, front

Hello guys i get my data from db with API i want to show data in frontend , i can do this
this is function, that return an array of data.

```
public function getComputerAttr($customerId) {

    $computerData = $this->computerFactory->create()->getData();
    $computers = [];

    foreach ($computerData as $computer){

        if( $computer['entity_id'] == $customerId) {

            $data = [

                "brand" => $computer['computer_brand'],
                "id" => $computer['entity_id'],
                "model" => $computer['computer_model']

             ];

            array_push($computers,$data);
        }
    }

    return $computers;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom phtml to display in the way you want the array,
Inside the xml of the kind of page you would like to display it to you declare your custom Block with your template.
In your custom Block you get the data from the model declared on the construct:

```
\Vendor\Module\Model\ComputerModel $computerFactory,
```

Inside your Block (Where you can get your customer Id from session or registry)

```
public function getComputerArray(){
   return $computerFactory->getComputerAttr($customerId)
}
```

then from your block to your Phtml

...xml

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Vendor/Module/Block/Your_block_file" name="computer.display" template="Vendor_Module::your_template.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Inside your Phtml:

```
Echo $block->getComputerArray();
```